# Thread Modelling

Tags: multithreading, modeling

In my university days I came across a Java app in one of my courses. You basically modeled your threads (any actions they perform etc.) in a simple language. It would draw a diagram and identify and issues with your threading. Does anyone know what this app is called? I have tried for the last 30 mins on Google but can't find anything.

Comment: Perhaps it was an app written by the faculty of your university for teaching purposes?  Have you considered asking the faculty for the reference?

Comment: are you talking about state diagram?

Comment: @McWafflestix, it wasn't written by the faculty, but going back to ask is a good idea... I don't know why I didn't think of that. Google syndrome I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean "Thread State Diagrams". Maybe something like this?

http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/objecteering_uml_modeler/diagrams/state_diagrams.htm

Comment: That's exactly the concept; but there was an application to create (and 'debug' those).